# Accessing webpage iframes in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm attempting to access the Apply Now button on the Indeed job application platform. When I click it it pops into a new frame inside of which I would like to access the elements. I've tested the code on other webpages and can successfully access elements of the iframes, but I get an error on this specific page.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Game%20Audio&start=10&vjk=836d4ff796e19392#')

iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
iframes
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="fdfc346e-535b-45ea-b127-fe5d386fd6b7", element="d699e195-e4f5-4430-9851-9d98a0af925d")>]

driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#input-applicant\.firstName')
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#input-applicant\.firstName')
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 597, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Sonorityscape\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #input-applicant\.firstName
```

Here's a link to the page:

https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Game%20Audio&start=10&vjk=836d4ff796e19392#

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are not clicking on the apply now button and frame is loading after clicking on it and it loads in the second iframe. the following code may help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\\Users\\Sonorityscape\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Game%20Audio&start=10&vjk=836d4ff796e19392#')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.indeed-apply-button-label').click() #click on apply now button

iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(frames[1])

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#input-applicant\.firstName').send_keys("firstname")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it reproduces the same error. Everything works fine up until the last line. For some reason the CSS selector is not working.

Comment: Try with xpath otherwise

Comment: updated the code to wait for frame to load, please try now with updated answer.

Comment: I have executed line by line in Python and it does not work. I don't think timing is an issue.